# Convert a path to absolute path

Tags: java, path, nio

I have a path object that needs to be converted to absolute path.

```
Path path = Paths.get("..\\this\\that\\blah.txt");

System.out.println(path.toFile().getCanonicalPath());
```

This is skipping the main project folder due to which I can't access the file. I want something like:

```
C:\Folder\ProjectFolder\this\\that\\blah.txt
```

instead of

```
C:\Folder\this\\that\\blah.txt
```

Comment: Take out the ..\\ at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling that @Brian Gordon is right and you just need to do:

```
Path path = Paths.get("this\\that\\blah.txt");
```

instead of:

```
Path path = Paths.get("..\\this\\that\\blah.txt");
```

`..` represents the **parent** directory.
So, if you're in `C:\Folder\ProjectFolder`, `..` represents `C:\Folder`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get the absolute path from where you call the file itself.

Example:

```
    File blah = new File("/this/that/blah.txt");
    String blahAP = blah.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("AP: " + blahAP);
```

This should work, but I have no computer around me at the moment to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `getAbsolutePath` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile()